# In Node and coffee-script, finding a particular process running using the equivalient of ps,grep and awk

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Assuming that there isn't an easy way to get currently running process info from an node api (if you know of a good api let me know, since I couldn't find one), it looks like I need to use a command like **ps** (in Linux/OSx).

Here is the code that I can run on a terminal to get me the info that I need

```
ps ax | grep "node-webkit.*remote-debugging-port.*nw-apps" | awk '{ print $7 }'
```

And here is the Coffee-script code that does produces the same output:

```
  it.only 'find_Process', (done)->
      if process.platform is 'win32'
        done()
      else
        'ps'.start_Process_Capture_Console_Out 'ax', (data)->
          regex = /node-webkit.*remote-debugging-port.*nw-apps/
          matches = for line in data.split('\n') when regex.exec(line)
                      line.split(' ')[15]
          log matches
          done()
```

So my questions are if this the better way to get write this in coffee-script, and if there is a better way to achieve this in a multi-platform way (it with windows support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing since there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this at the moment (Jan 2015)

Answer (score 0):

You could try executing your shellcode using shelljs, if that's an option. "[https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs"](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs)

EDIT:
You can try:

`shell.exec('ps aux', function(err, data){
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(data);
})`

Comment: shelljs looks great, but at the moment it doesn't support ps (I asked about it here https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs/issues/170 )

Comment: Have you tried putting that inside shell exec? I did a simple ps aux and that seemed to work.